Why is SRP batcher breaking GPU Instancing?
So I was making this demo scene where there are tons of shells(green little rectangles), and they come from a prefab with shader and material that supports GPU instancing. But when I check the FrameDebugger, I noticed that my shell draw calls are broken into 2 different draw calls. And the cause was just confusing to me: SRP Batcher.


As far as I know, the SRP batcher was not compatible with GPU Instancing in the first place. Why would SRP batcher just randomly has anything to do with GPU Instancing? Did it just randomly decide to break my draw call batch? What should I do to restore the batch?
